# ASP.net MVC Model failing to recognise values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As part of my current project I've blundered into an enormous MVC web form that I know relatively little about, and am having to do some fairly serious debugging on it. I have plenty of WebForms experience but little with MVC so please forgive me if the following isn't clear, or is asking silly questions.

Part of the form is a custom .ascx control which gets information from another URL and limits what the user can put into that section of the form based on that information. All the form elements can be turned on and off. If you turn this particular form element on, fill it in and submit then the ModelState fails its validation check, complaining that its missing a required value. The form is returned with the problematic element switched on, but no values in the boxes. If you don't switch on this particular element, the ModelState validates properly.

I know enough about MVC to understand that the mapping between form elements and the model occurs under the hood. However this makes it very difficult to debug. I really have no idea what the problem is or, worse, how to go about investigating what the cause is. Any suggestions on either front would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Some code

```
//start to deal with specialist form user controls        
case    "ViewData.Customer.CustomFieldTypes.BlackWhiteListConfigViewData ":        
 if (Model.Visible)
   { %>
 <div class="formItem">
   <label>
    <%      Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/BlackWhiteListConfigViewData.ascx"); %>
</div>
<% }
   else
   { %>
 <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Value) %>
<% }
 b break;
```

And the binding code:

```
  switch (fieldType)
            {
                case FeatureFieldFactory.BlackWhiteListConfigElTypeName:
                    {
                        // create a new default model binder, and tell it which type we actually want it to bind.
                        BlackWhiteListConfigViewData model = new BlackWhiteListConfigViewData();
                        bindingContext.ModelMetadata =
                            ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, typeof(BlackWhiteListConfigViewData));

                        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
                    }
```

EDIT: BlackWhiteListConfigViewData.ascx code

if (Model.Visible)
        { %>

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(cpContext.CurrentService()).bind('onServiceAttributesReady', function (context) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#js-hook-BlackWhiteListLoading").hide();
                if (context.target.AttributeNames().length === 0) {
                    $("#js-hook-AddBlackWhiteListEntry").hide();
                    $("#js-hook-BlackWhiteListConfigTable").hide();
                    $("#js-hook-BlackWhiteListMessage").html('There are no attribute types present in the catalogue.  The Black and White lists can be configured once the catalogue is loaded.');
                    $("#js-hook-BlackWhiteListMessage").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#js-hook-BlackWhiteListMessage").hide();
                    $("#js-hook-AddBlackWhiteListEntry").show();
                    $("#js-hook-BlackWhiteListConfigTable").show();
                }
            });
        });

        $(cpContext.CurrentService()).bind('onServiceAttributesError', function (context) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#js-hook-BlackWhiteListLoading").hide();
                $("#js-hook-AddBlackWhiteListEntry").hide();
                $("#js-hook-BlackWhiteListConfigTable").hide();
                $("#js-hook-BlackWhiteListMessage").html('No attribute types retrieved from service API.  The Black and White lists can be configured when a Build has been completed and service API is accessible.');
                $("#js-hook-BlackWhiteListMessage").show();
            });
        });

        cpContext.CurrentService().getAttributes();
    </script> 

    <div class="formItem narrow blackWhiteListConfig">
        <% using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("fields"))
           {
               Model.Value = "n/a";
        %>

            <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Id) %>
            <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Type) %>
            <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Name) %>
            <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Visible) %>
            <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.DisplayName) %>
            <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Value) %>

            <table id="js-hook-BlackWhiteListConfigTable" class="configTable" style="display:none">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th class="configTableColumn">Key Attribute Type</th><th class="configTableColumn">Key Value</th><th class="transparent"></th><th class="configTableColumn">Related Attribute Type</th><th class="configTableColumn">Related Attribute Value</th><th class="configTableColumn narrow">Black</th><th class="configTableColumn narrow">White</th><th class="transparent" style="width:20px"></th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="blackWhiteListRows">
                <% foreach (BlackWhiteListEntryViewData entry in Model.Entries)
                   { %>
                        <%= Html.EditorForNested(e => entry) %>
                <% } %>
                </tbody>
            </table>

               <hr />
                <p id="js-hook-AddBlackWhiteListEntry" class="clear" style="display:none"><a  href="#">Add another entry</a></p>
                <p id="js-hook-BlackWhiteListMessage" class="clear" style="display:none">There are no attribute types present in the catalogue.  The Black and White lists can be configured once the catalogue is loaded.</p>
                <img id="js-hook-BlackWhiteListLoading" src="<%=Links.Content.images.content_loading_gif %>" alt="Loading Black and White list configuration..."
                     style="" class="clear" />
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model) %>
    <% } %>
```

Model.Value) %>

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Could you elaborate on where or how a form element is turned on/off?

Comment: It's checkbox based. Form elements by default are type="hidden", and this is removed via javascript when the box is checked. Clearly in this instance the element is being unhidden and stays unhidden, but no textboxes within it are keeping their values.

Comment: Well, it sounds like the POST value might not be binding properly. Could you give more information about: (1) the view code generating that particular form element (2) the property it is binding to

Comment: Edited post to show what appears to be the relevant code

Comment: I think the code from this view (file) would be handy: `BlackWhiteListConfigViewData.ascx`

Comment: Added. Thanks for looking. If it's any help, this did work at some point and looking at the code history I've noticed that the control rendering used be done with Html.EditorFor and is now done with Html.RenderPartial - could this be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/BlackWhiteListConfigViewData.ascx"); %>
```

with:

```
<%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
```

or if your model type is not `BlackWhiteListConfigViewData` you could specify it:

```
<%= Html.EditorForModel("BlackWhiteListConfigViewData") %>
```

Also inside your editor template you seem to be using some custom helpers such as `Html.EditorForNested`. Make sure your input field names respect the [conventions for binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

Comment: EditorForModel still results in the same error. As does EditorFor. I have not checked the binding conventions as yet though - will do so now.